# Hibernate query language for JSONB syntax

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql, jsonb

My query string:

```
SELECT COUNT (id) 
FROM local.test.entity.ABCTest 
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT testInfo FROM jsonb_array_elements(test_info) AS testInfo 
    WHERE (VALUE  ->> testId)::TEXT = ?0
    )
```

I'm trying to create an HQL for JsonB but when calling function `createQuery()` of EntityManager exception occurred.

When checking the log I saw that:

```
[0;39m Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
[0;39m     findClass(jsonb_array_elements)
[0;39m     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
[0;39m QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@7350cc69
[0;39m line 1:112: unexpected token: jsonb_array_elements
```

So it means HQL does not support JsonB? or my syntax does not correct?

Do you have any info about that

Thank you.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using JsonB of PostgreSQL.(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html)

Comment: OK, HQL does not support jsonb function. We need to build a native SQL for that...